# How do I recover bitcoin sent to a wrong wallet address

Tags: transactions

I mistakenly sent bitcoin to the wrong wallet address... How can I recover the money back or get the information of the person I sent the money to?

Comment: Short answer: typically you cannot do either.  Your coins are gone.  Sorry.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50086/is-there-any-chance-to-check-the-name-by-bitcoin-hash

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to reverse a transaction based on the design of Bitcoin.

You may be able to contact the receiver of your bitcoin by googling the address (some mining pool addresses are publicly known), but also by sending a message to the address through the use of the [OP_RETURN](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_RETURN) opcode. This will allow you to embed a message in the blockchain via including it in a transaction to the address you mistakenly sent your Bitcoin to. It is possible the owner of private key that corresponds to that address (if there is one) will notice your message and decide to return your funds.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Any payments on bitcoins are irreversible.](https://bitcoin.org/en/you-need-to-know) The website says that you should contact the receiver and get it refunded.

Comment: Try to avoid posting just a link and a short regurgitation of what the link has to say.  Answer the question yourself, using the link as a resource to back up your answer, and you are likely to get more upvotes.