# Is there any chance to check the name by bitcoin hash?

Tags: hash, privacy

Someone recently wants to sell me an iPhone, but the seller does not want to show me anything about it. It's a second-hand phone, and I'm worried about it a little bit. Is there any chance to see the information about the seller from bitcoin hash?

Comment: What Bitcoin hash? How is Bitcoin even related to this? Are they selling the phone for BTC, and expecting you to pay to their address? If you could get some information from that, why couldn't they give their friends' address instead?

Comment: they just send me the bitcoin hash and told me pay to that, after that we sending the phone to you, because of that I ask this question !

Comment: You should know that if you make the payment in Bitcoin, you are absolutely trusting the seller to actually send the iPhone.  If they decide not to send it and just keep the money, they can do that; you will have no way to recover your money.  Bitcoin has no fraud chargebacks like credit cards and Paypal do.  And you will not be able to track down the seller through a Bitcoin address alone.  So unless you have complete trust in this seller, don't pay.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. Bitcoin is [pseudonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonymity). In all likelihood, you will be sent an address which never had any activity on it before. You can't find any relation between that address and the real world (including activity on the blockchain) until a transaction sending money to that address is published. Even if you knew the person who gave you the address, you wouldn't know for sure whether it belongs to them (but you'd of course assume it because why would they give you an address of a different person or one which belongs to no one). They can prove that it belongs to them but they can't prove that it doesn't and you as someone it doesn't belong to can't proof they own it nor that they don't.

Answer (score -1):

no. it is not possible to know your name but indirectly they can keep record the track of your bitcoin transaction as each and every transaction is recorded in a public ledger